# Idiomatic bash way to run optional action without side effects on exit code

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit, exit-status

This script will exit with test result which is not desired from callers perspective. How it should be implemented instead?

```
#!/bin/bash
test -n "" && echo "test passed"
```

Comment: if the caller cares about the exit code, then i cant understand how anything else would be desirable. if i called a program which only tested if a null-string was not-null and it returned true, it would upset me.

Comment: No, it exits with the result of `echo` if the test was successful and `test` if it wasn't. That said, what is your desired behavior? What should it exit with?

Answer (score 3):

Just add an explicit:

```
exit 0
```

at the end of your script if you don't want to report any failure.

You can also do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
ret=0

cmd || ret=$? # we care about the failure of cmd

test -n "" && echo test # we don't care about the failure of test or echo

exit "$ret"
```

For your particular example, you could rewrite it:

```
test -z "" || echo test passed
```

(that would still report an error if `echo` failed, but you may want to report that one as that would indicate something bad)

Or:

```
test -n "" && echo test passed || : ignore
```

The `:` command always returns with a *success* exit status.